# Is there an Xbox One control API?

Tags: xbox

I am wondering if there is an API for Xbox One that allows you to boot it up (similar to how the Xbox App on Windows 10 can boot it up) amongst other things?

Comment: Do you mean a Windows 10 API that allows you to send the wake up call to your Xbox or an API for a UWP running on the Xbox?

To my knowledge neither exists, however one could likely find out with a tool like Wireshark what the Windows 10 App sends to the Xbox to wake it up and simply send the same data. It's not a regular Wake on LAN magic packet unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, a Windows 10 API that allows you to send the wake up call. Good idea about Wireshark, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

There is an API, but it appears to be proprietary and probably won't be released by Microsoft.  I've created a node.js module, however, that lets you turn it on from Windows, OSX, and Linux, provided you know the IP address and Live ID.  You can find it here:  https://github.com/arcreative/xbox-on

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox Device Portal REST API is now public.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/reference